# How can I plot a graph on python from multiple csv files?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, matplotlib

This are the `csv` files I have:

```
bmi_per_country_female.csv 
bmi_per_country_male.csv 
coffee- consumption-by-country-2024.csv
eye-color percentage-by-country-2024.csv
Life_ecpectancy_female_1960-2021.csv
mean_height_per_countries_age_specific.csv
total-alcohol-consumption-per-capital-litres-of-pure-alcohol.csv)
```

i have the above `csv` files in one folder named 'Data' on my `PyCharm` the aim is to plot a line graph that shows the amount of people in each country that use coffee, alcohol, their eye color, life expectancy, their height and so on from the `csv` files.

I am new for programmingm and I appreciate any guidance.

any suggestion is appreciated.

I want it to look something like this:

[image: i want it to look something like this.]

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example that might help you.

Save your samples in a subfolder "Data".

`coffee-consumption-by-country-2024.csv`:

```
Country,Coffee_Consumption
USA,4.5
Canada,3.8
Germany,5.2
Brazil,4.8
Japan,3.6
```

`total-alcohol-consumption-per-capita-litres-of-pure-alcohol.csv`:

```
Country,Alcohol_Consumption
USA,8.7
Canada,9.1
Germany,11.8
Brazil,7.2
Japan,7.0
```

With these, you load your files on a pandas dataframe and merge them together.

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Read CSV files
coffee_df = pd.read_csv('Data/coffee-consumption-by-country-2024.csv')
alcohol_df = pd.read_csv('Data/total-alcohol-consumption-per-capita-litres-of-pure-alcohol.csv')

# Assuming both CSV files have a 'Country' column and a data column
# Rename the data columns for clarity if necessary
coffee_df.columns = ['Country', 'Coffee_Consumption']
alcohol_df.columns = ['Country', 'Alcohol_Consumption']

# Merge the DataFrames on the 'Country' column
merged_df = pd.merge(coffee_df, alcohol_df, on='Country', how='inner')

# Plotting
plt.figure(figsize=(10, 6))
plt.plot(merged_df['Country'], merged_df['Coffee_Consumption'], label='Coffee Consumption')
plt.plot(merged_df['Country'], merged_df['Alcohol_Consumption'], label='Alcohol Consumption')
plt.xlabel('Country')
plt.ylabel('Consumption')
plt.title('Coffee and Alcohol Consumption by Country')
plt.xticks(rotation=90)
plt.legend()
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

Comment: it will look like this https://imgur.com/a/qjvxQlD